# Swift - Dictionary .last(where:

Tags: swift, dictionary, where-clause

Why I can't use `.last(where:` in dictionary of type: `[TimeInterval : [String : (amount: Double, ids: [Int64])]]`

Only `.first(where:` works.

I need last key where `String = "something"`

How to make it work ?

Comment: Show actual code.

Comment: “Last” would imply some sort of order. A dictionary is an unordered collection. None of its elements are first or last or in any relative position to any other elements.

Comment: You might want to check out [`KeyValuePairs`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyvaluepairs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your question.

1. Dictionaries are unordered, so the notion of first is not really defined. You can use [`KeyValuePairs`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyvaluepairs) instead.
2. > I need last key where `String = "something"`

   does not specify whether you want that to be the only key or not. I assume the latter.

This should get you what you want:

```swift
let dict: KeyValuePairs<TimeInterval, [String: (amount: Double, ids: [Int64])]> = [
    0: ["something": (0.0, [])],
    4: ["foo": (1.0, [3])],
    10: ["something": (4.0, [4,2,1])]
]

vals.first { $1["something"] != nil }?.key // => 0

vals.reversed().first { $1["something"] != nil }?.key // => 10
```